# Get the author ID - Wordpress, WP Job Manager

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using Wp Job Manager plugin with `job_listing` as the post_type

On single job listing page, I am trying to show the list of all job listing posted by the same user > author.

I can't figure out how to correctly get the ID of the author of the post

I've been trying with `'author' => get_current_user_id()` query, but that's not it.

This only fetches the ID of the current user, which is me as I'm logged in, and shows all my listings.

How can I get the the author of the post that I'm currently viewing?

This is what I'm currently trying, but it will only show my own listings as a logged in user:

```
function my_query_args($query_args, $grid_name) {
    if ($grid_name == 'author-listings') {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        // all query parameters can be modified (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)
        $query_args['author'] = $current_user->ID;
    }

    return $query_args;

}
add_filter('tg_wp_query_args', 'my_query_args', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the author ID, try 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/

To simply display it, try https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_author_meta/

So you could try

```
$query_args['author'] = $get_the_author_meta('ID');
```

Comment: Many thanks Michael .. I just edited my question and added an example of the full query that I'm currently trying to use .. Would you be able to see if you could correct it?

Comment: By the way, I'm using The Grid plugin to display the listings, so if the $grid_name equals to author-listings it will show the job_listings

Answer (score 0):

`global $post;
$author_id = $post->post_author;`

If $post is undefined, are you really on a single page or is the setup you have working its' own magic?